# std::shared_ptr Class Factory C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, shared-ptr, factory-pattern

We have a base class.....

```
class Node
{
   public:
      std::string Name;
      Node(){};
      ~Node(){};
}
```

**Filter** is a derived class of **Node**. 
**Filter** is the same a node, except it has a 'filterId' property and it's constructor populates **Node**.Name='Filter'.

```
class Filter: public Node
{
   public:
      int filterId;
      Filter() : Node()
      {
         Name="Filter";
      }
}
```

I have a ClassFactory that returns `std::shared_ptr<Node>` when passed a string

Please find the code to that factory on CodeProject following this link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/567242/AplusC-b-bplusObjectplusFactory.

The code seems to instantiate a **Filter**, but, returns a **Node**. i.e. Object slicing.

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> n = std::make_shared(Node);  // As expected, doesn't not have filter ID and node.Name is blank.
std::shared_ptr<Filter> f = std::make_shared(Filter);  // As expected, has filterID and node.Name is 'Filter'.
```

Now i want to handle an array of std::shared_ptr(Node) which may actually contain std::shared_ptr(Filter) depending on what the class is requested from the factory.

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> nf = std::make_shared(Filter);     // Error. Does not have filterId, but does have **Node**.Name='Filter'.
```

I even tried the simpler case..... and got the same problem.

```
Node n = Node();
Filter f = Filter();
Node nf =Filter();   // Error, nf does not have a filterID, but it's Name field is set to 'Filter'.
```

What am i doing wrong here? The **Node** is a base class for all of my derived classes. When i have a function that accepts a **Node**, i should be able to send it a **Filter** and have the filterId available.

Pointers are advised to help in situations like this, however the shared_ptr is a pointy as things will get.

Comment: boost have shared_dynamic_cast

Answer (score 1):

`Node` doesn't have any knowledge of additional data members and functions that derived classes may define. So you need to retrieve a `shared_ptr<Filter>` to be able to access `filterId`. Use [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) to do this.

```
std::shared_ptr<Node> n = ...
auto f = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Filter>(n);

if(f) {
    // The managed object is a Filter
    std::cout << f->filter_id << '\n';
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6066251c38918cab)

And if you know that `n` always contains a `Filter` (or something derived from `Filter`), you can use `std::static_pointer_cast` instead.

Comment: So, if i have a vector of mixed nodes and filters, how can i keep track of what to cast them to?

Comment: @user2723463 I initially wrote use `static_pointer_cast`, but then updated my answer to use `dynamic_pointer_cast` instead. The latter addresses your question. If you try to `dynamic_pointer_cast` a `Node` to `Filter`, the resulting `shared_ptr` will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

When you have any manner of pointer or reference to the base class, you can only access the things that the base class API exposes.  If you want to access `filterId`, you need to either:

- add it to the base interface (perhaps with a function that returns a `boost::optional<int>`, or pair `true,filterId` when available, otherwise e.g. `false,0`) or
- see if you can `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` to the `Filter` type, if the returned pointer is `true` in a boolean context, you can use it to access the `filterId`.